# Grouping Multiple Instances of a Value into an Array in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the following DataFrame:

```
CustomerID  Products_Purchased
0   1   A
1   2   B
2   3   C
3   4   D
4   1   E
5   2   F
6   3   G
7   4   H
```

and I'd like to group the products purchased by a customer into an array of comma separated values against the `CustomerID` as shown below:

```
    CustomerID  Products_Purchased
0   1   A, E
1   2   B, F
2   3   C, G
3   4   D, H
```

Please Advise.

*DataFrames can be reproduced using the following code:*

```
df_dict = {
    'CustomerID' : [1 , 2 , 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Products_Purchased' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

result_dict = {
    'CustomerID' : [1 , 2 , 3, 4],
    'Products_Purchased' : ['A, E', 'B, F', 'C, G', 'D, H'],
}
result = pd.DataFrame(result_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `groupby()` and `agg()`:

```
out=df.groupby('CustomerID')['Products_Purchased'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()
#OR
out=df.groupby('CustomerID').agg({'Products_Purchased':', '.join}).reset_index()
```

output of out:

```
  CustomerID    Products_Purchased
0   1           A, E
1   2           B, F
2   3           C, G
3   4           D, H
```